# using isocalendar with datetime

Tags: python, django, python-datetime

I have datetime field

```
 start_date = datetime.today()-timedelta(days= 30*num)
```

not i want to get week number

```
Week = start_date.isocalander()[1]
```

I am finding problem in converting date to week number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to check the spelling from the docs or using `dir()`

```
>>> start_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
>>> start_date
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 24, 13, 37, 11, 869997)
>>> start_date.isocalendar()[1]
30
```